# changing aesthetic ggplot2 layer object inside function

Tags: r, ggplot2

i am trying to change an aesthetic of a geom that wasnt defined in the original plot call.

for example shape and size

```
p=iris%>%ggplot(aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Sepal.Width,colour=Species))+geom_point()+theme_bw()

change_shape=function(a){
  a$layers[[1]]$aes_params[['shape']]=5
  a$layers[[1]]$aes_params[['size']]=10
  return(a)
}

pnew=change_shape(p)
p
```

[image: same p different shape and size]

Comment: is it not changing?

Comment: the function changes the inputted object even though i dont directly change it. i change the local variable a not p a$layers[[1]]$aes_params[['shape']]=5

Comment: `return(a)` is returning a changed_p to the global environment, regardless of whether you assign that value to a new variable

Comment: I don't understand why arent p and pnew different?

Comment: Because when you did `change_shape(p)`, you changed `p` as Nathan Day said. The function contains `return(p)` which changes `p` in the environment.

Comment: Then how can I change it to get two different plots?

Comment: It has to do with `ggplot` using lazy eval. `ggplots` are not built and stored when they are defined, only read and built when they are called to render. And since stuff has been altered in the original then the altered version appears

Comment: then can i pass the object another way into the function as to not change the original?

Comment: why doesnt this help?             `p=iris%>%ggplot(aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Sepal.Width,colour=Species))+geom_point()+theme_bw()`
    `p0=p`
    `pnew=change_shape(p0)`

Comment: Maybe use a local variable inside of change_shape, b, and assign a to it then return b.

Comment: Does it matter if I change environments in lazyeval?

Comment: looks like a bug to me (i'm guessing a weird feature of ggproto)

Comment: is there a way to force a disconnect between the layer and the plot object? if i do p1=p;a=p1$layer[[1]]; p1$layer[[1]]=NULL; a[['size']]=3 it still is changing automatically the layer in p. which is saying that they are mapped to each other in some way. where can i find this connection to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

clone a layer (l) from an existing plot object and have it not connect to the original plot

```
cloneLayer=function(l){
   layer.names=c('mapping','data','geom','position',
            'stat','show.legend','inherit.aes',
            'aes_params','geom_params','stat_params')
   x=sapply(layer.names,function(y){
    b=l[[y]]

    if('waiver'%in%class(b)) b=NULL

    if(y=='geom') b=eval(parse(text=class(b)[1]))

    if(y%in%c('position','stat')) {
        b=gsub(y, "", tolower(class(b)[1]))
      }

    b
  }) 
x$params=append(x$stat_params,x$geom_params)
x$params=append(x$params,x$aes_params)
x$params=x$params[!duplicated(names(x$params))]
x$geom_params<-x$aes_params<-x$stat_params<-NULL
do.call(layer,x)
}
```