# ggplot2 objects not copy-on-modify?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an object (`line_and_shape`) that consists of a list of `ggplot2` layers. I have a function (`aes_changer`) that modifies the layers in `line_and_shape`, but I do not explicitly overwrite `line_and_shape`. However, after running the function, `line_and_shape` behaves as though it was overwritten. This is best shown with an example:

```
library(ggplot2)

# An object with some ggplot2 layers that can be added to any plot
line_and_shape <- list(
  geom_path(data=data.frame(x = c(19, 18, 20, 18), y = c(20, 21, 18, 17)), aes(x = x, y = y)),
  geom_hline(yintercept = 16)
)

# A function that iterates over a list of ggplot2 layers and modifies their aes
aes_changer <- function(layer_object, colour = "green", alpha = 1){
  for(ii in 1:length(layer_object)){
    layer_object[[ii]]$aes_params$colour <- colour
    layer_object[[ii]]$aes_params$alpha <- alpha
  }
  return(layer_object)
}

# A ggplot
ggplot(mtcars) +
  aes(x = mpg, y = qsec) +
  geom_point()

# (1) A ggplot, with portable layers added. Note that the lines are black
ggplot(mtcars) +
  line_and_shape +
  aes(x = mpg, y = qsec) +
  geom_point()

# (2) A ggplot with portable layers added, but altered so that the lines are red
ggplot(mtcars) +
  aes_changer(line_and_shape, colour = "red") +
  aes(x = mpg, y = qsec) +
  geom_point()

# (3) The same code as (1), but the lines are red, not black!
ggplot(mtcars) +
  line_and_shape +
  aes(x = mpg, y = qsec) +
  geom_point()

# Compare to:
triple <- function(x) {
  x <- 3*x
  x
}
a <- 5
triple(a)
a
```

My questions are:

1. How can I re-write `aes_changer` to *not* modify the original `line_and_shape`?
2. Why does this happen for `aes_changer`/`line_and_shape`, but not for `triple`/`a`?

Comment: Sounds similar to the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40442708/8449629).